# How to link some object file on macOS by using ld?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, compiler-errors, linker

Now, I am learning how to write assembly language. So, I wrote a assemble file named test_func.S and a C source file main.c. And I compiled those files, for test_func.S, I use the "as" to compile "test_func.S"
For test_func.S, I just define a empty function. The following is my code in test_func.S.

```
.globl test_func
test_func:
    movl $99, %eax
    ret
```

My main.c is also very easy. Just call the function I defined in test_func.S. The following is my code.

```
extern int test_func();
int main() {
    return test_func();
}
```

First, I use **as** to compile my test_func.S. The following is my command on terminal.

`as -arch i386 test_func.S -o test_func.o`

Next, I use **clang** to compile "main.c".

```
clang -m32 -c main.c -o main.o
```

In order to generate an executable file, the last step is to link those object file into an executable file. I use the following command.

```
clang -m32 test_func.o main.o -o main
```

However, **ld** generate an error :

`"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_test_func", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386"`

I use the same command and the same source file in another computer which is running ubuntu system, everything is OS.
when I `echo $?`, the result is 99. So, where is wrong in my steps on macOS?

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo on the last line. everything is OK instead of OS.

Comment: mac uses underscore prefix apparently. So change your assembly file to use `_test_func` as the error says.

Comment: @linyuwang: You can (and should) use the [edit] button to correct typos in your question when you notice a mistake.  That's much better than just commenting about it.